# VBA - how to hide rows if cell contains a specified value

Tags: vba, hide

I'm fairly new to VBA and can't figure out the answer to this question by looking at other posts:

I want to use VBA to hide any rows where the text of cells A18:A153 equal the value "Hide" and also unhide any rows where these cells equal the value "Unhide". So, if cell A22 = "Hide" row 22 should be hidden. And if cell A23 = "Unhide" row 23 should be unhidden.

I tried this code to hide cells but it didn't work, so I didn't attempt unhiding cells:

```
With Worksheets("Report")
  For i = 18 To 153       
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 1).Value = "Hide" 
      Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True        
    End If    
  Next i
End With
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I added the code I have tried.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What happens when you run it? 2. the problem is likely that you've insufficiently enumerated the location of the cells. If you're running this code from the worksheet with the values in `A` that you want to evaluate, try `ActiveSheet.Cells` instead of simply `Cells`.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do this for several specific worksheets in my file, and I left off the With statement. I updated my code to reflect that, sorry for the omission.

Comment: The error I get is "Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo"

Comment: move the word `then` to the same line as the `if` leave the rest of that line where it is

Comment: Works! Thanks Yorik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use `with` and `if-then` correctly, the following code should work:

```
With Worksheets("Report")
  For i = 18 To 153    
    If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Hide" Then 
       .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True    
    End If
  Next i
End With
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!